# ios app crashes in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

What does this mean when I tried to build:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/chris/Developer/Happy People - Parse/User.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the file `user.m` is appearing in red color(link is missing), just delete it and add it again. If it is not in red color just remove the reference(while deleting remove reference only) and add it again

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you deleted the file from your disk but didn't remove it form the project inside XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is not able to locate the `User.m` file. It might be removed or relocated.